# TensorFlow 2.1 with NVidia GPU returning Warnings and Errors on: missing libraries, NUMA, Convolution operation

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I ma trying to train a Neural Network in `tensorflow 2.1.0`. I have installed all the necessary software to configure my NVidia RTX 2070 GPU. In fact, when I type: `tf.test.is_gpu_available()` I get `True`.

However, this is what started to happened to me when I `import tensorflow as tf`, at the beginning of each run. This appears in the terminal:

```
2020-05-08 10:07:48.506283: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libnvinfer.so.6
2020-05-08 10:07:48.506523: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.6'; dlerror: libnvrtc.so.10.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-05-08 10:07:48.506534: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:30] Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
2020-05-08 10:07:49.047809: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-05-08 10:07:49.084978: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-08 10:07:49.085264: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2070 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.44GHz coreCount: 36 deviceMemorySize: 7.79GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2020-05-08 10:07:49.085420: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-05-08 10:07:49.085476: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-05-08 10:07:49.086628: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-05-08 10:07:49.086807: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-05-08 10:07:49.087975: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-05-08 10:07:49.088620: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-05-08 10:07:49.088643: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-05-08 10:07:49.088700: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-08 10:07:49.088997: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-08 10:07:49.089251: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
```

And later, when the actual model training starts, I get:

```
2020-05-08 10:07:49.235606: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-05-08 10:07:49.258082: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2599990000 Hz
2020-05-08 10:07:49.258706: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x5c2fe60 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-05-08 10:07:49.258733: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-05-08 10:07:49.330241: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-08 10:07:49.330585: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x5c1e240 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-05-08 10:07:49.330600: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce RTX 2070, Compute Capability 7.5
2020-05-08 10:07:49.330749: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-08 10:07:49.331031: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2070 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.44GHz coreCount: 36 deviceMemorySize: 7.79GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2020-05-08 10:07:49.331057: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-05-08 10:07:49.331065: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-05-08 10:07:49.331072: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-05-08 10:07:49.331100: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-05-08 10:07:49.331108: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-05-08 10:07:49.331116: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-05-08 10:07:49.331135: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-05-08 10:07:49.331185: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-08 10:07:49.331517: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-08 10:07:49.331778: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-05-08 10:07:49.331799: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-05-08 10:07:49.332395: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1096] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-05-08 10:07:49.332404: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102]      0 
2020-05-08 10:07:49.332408: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] 0:   N 
2020-05-08 10:07:49.332499: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-08 10:07:49.332793: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-08 10:07:49.333078: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1241] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6381 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
```

and

```
2020-05-08 10:08:04.498028: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-05-08 10:08:04.798897: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-05-08 10:08:05.159827: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
2020-05-08 10:08:05.161453: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
2020-05-08 10:08:05.161572: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:217] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node model/conv1d/conv1d}}]]
2020-05-08 10:08:05.163161: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
2020-05-08 10:08:05.163198: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1655] OP_REQUIRES failed at cudnn_rnn_ops.cc:1510 : Unknown: Fail to find the dnn implementation.
2020-05-08 10:08:05.163233: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:217] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Unknown: Fail to find the dnn implementation.
     [[{{node CudnnRNN}}]]
```

and

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[node model/conv1d/conv1d (defined at home/ivan/Documents/ML/projects/rnn/wtf_imputation/GAN-RNN_Timeseries-imputation/train.py:71) ]] [Op:__inference_train_on_batch_5414]
```

The `Failed to get convolution algorithm` is something I had solved in the past by adding this block at the beginning of my training script:

```
import tensorflow as tf
# Solves Convolution CuDNN error
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
    try:
        for gpu in gpus:
            tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
    except RuntimeError as e:
        print(e)
```

But this time it doesn't work and I don't really understand why.

---

EDIT:

Even though it says I have CUDA 10.2, I actually installed the 10.1 version, as requested by TensorFlow. In fact, when I chec `nvcc --version` I get:

```
[...]
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

So I have the 10.1 version. I don' understand where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

### 1) Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries.

You either did not install the TensorRT libraries (they are independent from Tensorflow and CUDA and offer some specific - and optional - acceleration capabilities. You can safely ignore this for now, look into how to install the libraries (on [TF's install page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu)) for further info on how to install them.

### 2) Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR

This is normally caused by either not having CuDNN installed, or having the wrong version. Since it says `Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7`, I'm leaning towards the second option. Check that the version you installed matches the required one by Tensorflow (which may be an older one than the most recent available on NVIDIA's website).

<s>As a side-note, from your logs it seems you have CUDA 10.2 installed.</s> Tensorflow requires version 10.1, so that may be another source of problems. If that's the case, you can install version 10.1 along with version 10.2 on your system, or uninstall 10.2 and save some space.

**Edit**: The 10.2 in the logs refers to TensorRT libraries, the rest of the logs do list libraries with version 10.1, so the side-note is likely wrong.

Comment: Thanks. And what is the NUMA message above? Could it be related to that, or is it just a warning I can ignore for now?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but from my experience that message is shown when the GPU is masked or not found. It's also probably related to the incorrect CUDA setup and should go away once you install the correct version of the libraries

Comment: Hi, I have edited the Question. As it is shown, `nvcc --version` says I have the 10.1 version installed. I really don't understand what is going on.

Comment: Actually, the 10.2 seems related to the not-found TensorRT library. Everything else mentions 10.1, so I may be wrong on that. Can you `ls /usr/local` and see what cuda folders you have in there? (`/usr/local/cuda` is just a symlink to one of the versions installed)

Comment: in `/usr/local` I have both `cuda-10.1` and `cuda-10.2` folders.

Comment: Ok, so you have both versions installed. In theory, that shouldn't be an issue, as TF loads specifically libraries with `10.1`, but I can't test that, so I'm not quite sure whether that can be the source of your problems. The CUDNN internal error point to cuDNN, so I'd check that first.

Comment: I was having the same issues. I am running TensorFlow in an anaconda environment on Ubuntu 20.04. After many failed attempts the solution that worked for me was closing any program that was using hardware acceleration. In my case it was Brave browser and VS Code.

Comment: @anshdavid did you have any trouble installing CUDA on 20.04? AFAIK it's not yet supported by Nvidia

Comment: @GPhilo I am using Anaconda . So when I install tensorflow-gpu, it installs cuda and cudnn in the virtual environment rather that the whole system. I have `cudatoolkit 10.1.243` and `cudnn 7.6.5` installed.